# deserialize a JSON object with variable names in Java?

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I'm putting together my first personal project ever and Ive been racking my brain for the last few days now with this problem. I'm currently using the Gson package to deserialize Json objects that I receive from an API. As I currently understand it, deserializing and parsing data into Java objects using Gson require that the object names and variables inside the classes match, otherwise Gson will ignore them. Here is the affected code.

```
public class partsAvailability {
private partNumber partNumber;

public partNumber getpartNumber() {
    return partNumber;
}

public void setpartNumber(partNumber partnumber) {
    this.partNumber = partnumber;
}




public class partNumber {
private String pickupSearchQuote;

public String getPickupSearchQuote() {
    return pickupSearchQuote;
}

public void setPickupSearchQuote(String pickupSearchQuote) {
    this.pickupSearchQuote = pickupSearchQuote;
}
```

And the relevant JSON data looks like this (apologies for the formatting):

```
"partsAvailability": {

    "MQ8R3LL/A": {
        

        "pickupSearchQuote": "Unavailable for Pickup",
```

The API will return the requested part number (MQ8R3LLA) as the name of the object with all the information I need nested inside. Obviously the part number can change as the request can, so  Is there any way that I am able to retrieve the information inside the MQ8R3LL/A object without having to name the Java class after it?

EDIT: I solved it! I figured out that the JSON was actually already mapped in a LinkedTreeMap format. Since I only needed about 3-4 lines of information from the JSON itself, I just used the `.getAsJsonObject()` and `.getAsJsonArray()` respectively. I'm not sure if it's the most eloquent of ways to do this, so if there's any suggestions please let me know! Thank you so much to @Edwin-Dalarzo for pointing me in the right direction. If you guys are curious, here is the full program I was writing. Thanks again!!

https://github.com/the-beef-calculator/AppleStore-Inventory-Checker

Comment: I was reading your code and I noticed that some of your class names don’t follow the naming convention of using names in [PascalCase](https://wiki.c2.com/?PascalCase).  Are you sure Gson does not handle that automatically for you if you convert your class names to Pascal case e.g. `PartsAvailability` instead of `partsAvailability`? I’d be really surprised if it didn’t. See [this](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#json-field-naming-support), perhaps it can solve your problems.

Comment: @edwin-dalorzo Thank you for your reply, the documentation here explains the inverse of what I need haha. The object name inside the JSON `"MQ8R3LL/A"` is dynamic. If I request a different part number from the API, that object name will also change. I am trying to figure out a way to tell Java that to import the data from the `MQ8R3LL/A` object into the `partNumber` class. All the other parts of the JSON are deserializing  correctly when I use the direct name from the JSON (they're not shown here) except for this one. Currently `partsAvailability` still deserializes as `null` when I do.

Comment: You should consider mapping that to Map object perhaps

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo I'm taking that route now. I'll let you know how it goes! Thank you again.

Comment: What is the `partsAvailability` class for? Keep in mind that for Gson the field names matter, the class names are irrelevant. You could probably model your data similar to this: `static class Response { public Map<String, PartAvailability> partsAvailability; }` and then `static class PartAvailability { public String pickupSearchQuote; }`. Here `Response.partsAvailability` maps for example from `MQ8R3LL/A` to the corresponding data for that part.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo I fixed it! If you wouldn't mind sharing any feedback on how I could make the program better, Here's a link to the repository :) Thanks again!
https://github.com/the-beef-calculator/AppleStore-Inventory-Checker